# "Rule useless in parser" with two operators in a row

Tags: bison

I want to write a grammar with an operator like the Matlab colon operator, where "a:b" and "a:b:c" means slightly different things. And I'd prefer the operator to be nonassociative, since "a:b:c:d" etc wouldn't make sense.

Here's a stripped-down version of my grammar, to show how I've tried to do it:

```
%union {
  int ival;
}

%token tINT

%nonassoc ':'

%%

program: { }
       | expression ';' { }

expression: tINT { }
          | expression ':' expression { }
          | expression ':' expression ':' expression { }
```

For some reason, bison ignores the second colon rule, with this message:

```
test.y:16.13-56: warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts [-Wother]
           | expression ':' expression ':' expression { }
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why doesn't bison understand what I want here, and how can I change my grammar so it works?

Edit: in case it helps, the output from "bison -v" contains

```
State 7

    4 expression: expression . ':' expression
    4           | expression ':' expression .
    5           | expression . ':' expression ':' expression
    5           | expression ':' expression . ':' expression

    ':'  error (nonassociative)

    $default  reduce using rule 4 (expression)
```

though I still don't see why bison shouldn't allow this, nor how to solve it.

Comment: Change the order in which the colon productions are defined.  It's matching the short one first.  The second one can't ever fire.  Bison generates LR parsers by default.

Comment: Exchanging the order doesn't help, it just gives the same error on line 15 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified that the ':' operator is nonassociative. Remove that, and you'll instead get the expected conflicts from A:B:C being parsable as one of A:B:C, (A:B):C and A:(B:C).

But since you want it to be nonassociative, here is one way:

```
%token tINT

%%

program: { }
        | colonexpression ';' { }
        ;

colonexpression: expression { }
        | expression ':' expression ':' expression { }
        | expression ':' expression { }
        ;

expression: tINT { }
        ;

%%
```

Comment: Maybe, but my colon operator is not the only operator in the system, I also have arithmetic and conditionals etc, so it probably needs to have some kind of precedence. This seems like it would be messy to shoehorn in among the other operators, unless I threw out yacc-style precedence completely and just wrote *all* the rules recursive-descent-style instead? Ugly...

Comment: Well, I suppose if all else fails, I can use recursive-descent-style rules for all operators with lower precedence than colon (and Matlab has a fairly low precedence for it), while still using ordinary precedence for the operators with higher precedence. Hmmm...

Comment: @Ove: This will work fine with precedence relationships for other operators, as long as you manually divide the operators into two groups: those which have higher priority than : and those which have lower priority. One group goes into expression and the other group goes into colonexpression.

Comment: @rici: Interesting idea. But if you added more operators to colonexpression, then you probably would need to assign a precedence to the colon anyway, right? However, adding a third kind of expression might do the trick. That could work. Still, this way is kind of unsatisfactory... will think about it some more.

Comment: @ove: yes, you would have to put the colon in the precedence list. But it would be in the expected place. Personally I prefer not to use precedence except where the use is trivial because it can be very hard to reason about the result, as in your precedence-based solution, which doesn't strike me as being a readable grammar. As always, tastes vary;use the style you  prefer.

Comment: @rici: but this particular answer relied on *removing* it from the precedence list.

Comment: Okay, I'll go with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ah! After a lot of mucking about, I finally found a way that works and still allows me to use precedence the "right" way, though it requires me to assign a precedence to all terminals that can appear in an expression, if I want to avoid tons of shift/reduce warnings. Also it needs a dummy token to give the single-colon rule an appropriate precedence (a little lower than ':', in order to avoid the understandable shift-reduce conflict).

I'm not completely happy with having to assign precedence to terminals like tINT, since my real grammar has a bunch of such things, but I suppose this will have to do, if nobody has a better idea.

```
%union {
  int ival;
}

%token tINT

%precedence nCOLON
%nonassoc ':'
%precedence tINT

%%

expression: tINT { }
          | expression_colon expression %prec nCOLON { }
          | expression_colon expression ':' expression { }

expression_colon: expression ':'
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you simply make it left-associative with the appropriate precedence, then as part of your action code, throw an error if there's more than 2 colons?  That is, don't try to handle this in the grammar, but make it a semantic constraint, enforced in C code.

I'm thinking of something like this -- this is pure pseudocode, mind you, because I have no idea what sort of parse tree you're building, but let's assume you're building an abstract syntax tree --

```
expression
    : expression ':' expression
    {
        if (Head($1) == DoubleColon)
            yyerror("Three-colon expressions are not allowed.");
        else if (Head($1) == Colon)
            $$ = DoubleColon(element_of($1, 1), element_of($1, 2), $3);
        else
            $$ = Colon($1, $3);
    }
```

Depending on how you handle parentheses, this may get a little more complicated.  (I.e. if you encode them explicitly in the parse tree, you can use the above technique, but otherwise you'll need a way to distinguish `(a:b):c` from `a:b:c`.)

This is an interesting problem.  I faced it in a parser I was writing, and I was never able to come up with a general solution.  In my case, the two colons had different contexts and different precedences.  It seems like something a shift-reduce automaton ought to be able to do, but it's not clear how to tell Bison to generate the transition tables you want. Eventually I had to solve it with a lexer hack that calls back into the parser to do a "simulated parse," a technique that Bison 3.0 uses in its LAC feature.

Comment: I'm not encoding parentheses explicitly, so yes, this would be problematic.

Comment: Put a 1-bit flag in your semantic value for `expression` that you set in the parenthesis rule, but otherwise leave unset?  That's how I handled it.